# Replace None with 'N/A' in dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary

I need to replace `None` to `'N/A'` in list in dictionary please see the below code:

```
[{'Hello': 'Suriya', 'Age': None, 'Area': 'Technical', 'Speed': None}]
```

I unable to replace the `None` with `N/A` in list in dictionary

Comment: A simple list/dictionary comprehension will work for the data shown in the question. However, where values are lists or dictionaries you'll need a recursive approach

Answer (score 1):

Use a dictionary comprehension in a list comprehension:

```
lst = [{'Hello': 'Suriya', 'Age': None, 'Area': 'Technical', 'Speed': None}]

out = [{k: 'N/A' if v is None else v for k,v in d.items()} for d in lst]
```

If you have only one dictionary:

```
out = [{k: 'N/A' if v is None else v for k,v in lst[0].items()}]
```

Output:

```
[{'Hello': 'Suriya', 'Age': 'N/A', 'Area': 'Technical', 'Speed': 'N/A'}]
```

Comment: No i am getting this error AttributeError ("'list' object has no attribute 'items'")

Comment: Then you don't have a dictionary and your example in the question is not faithful, please update ;)

Comment: Yes it would be list. Not dictionary

Comment: Then `out = [{k: 'N/A' if v is None else v for k,v in d.items()} for d in lst]` assuming `lst` your list

Comment: Yes, Thanks I got the expected output